# Spark 3.2.0 Structured Streaming save data to Kafka with Confluent Schema Registry

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

Is there some easy way how to save a spark structured streaming dataframe into kafka with Confluent Schema registry? Spark version is 3.2.0, Scala 2.12

I managed to read data from Kafka with Confluent schema registry with a bit of an ugly code:

````
  val schemaRegistryClient = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(schemaRegistry, 128)
  val kafkaAvroDeserializer = new AvroDeserializer(schemaRegistryClient)
  val deserializer = kafkaAvroDeserializer
}

class AvroDeserializer extends AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer {
  def this(client: SchemaRegistryClient) {
    this()
    this.schemaRegistry = client
  }

  override def deserialize(bytes: Array[Byte]): String = {
    val genericRecord = super.deserialize(bytes).asInstanceOf[GenericRecord]
    genericRecord.toString
  }
}

spark.udf.register("deserialize", (bytes: Array[Byte]) =>
  DeserializerWrapper.deserializer.deserialize(bytes))```
````

Now I would like to write the data to another Kafka topic - is there a simple way?

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to use similarly ugly code that uses a serializer UDF over a Struct column (or primitive type).

There's libraries that can help with making it less ugly - https://github.com/AbsaOSS/ABRiS